# how to set variables on back press in navigationController swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34956946/4646999) , I wanted to pass some data from a B `viewController` to its parent, A `viewController`, on back press! here is my code :
in my B `viewController`, I've added this code -

```
    extension Bcontroller: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {

        (viewController as? Acontroller)?.number = numberInB
        (viewController as? Acontroller)?.myBoolean = boolInB

    }
}
```

and here is my code in A controller :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if number != -1 {
        print(myBoolean)
    }
}
```

when I open B controller, `navigationController (willShow)` is called, and when I press back button, `viewWillAppear` is called first, and then `navigationController(willShow)` in B controller is called! so my data is not set, and  `number` will be always `-1` . how can I set these variable?

Comment: The best way to achieve it by using delagation.

Comment: see this for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955987/pass-data-through-navigation-back-button/34956946

Comment: @ketakiDamale can you write me an example?

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I used exactly this question and the answer which is checked! but It's not working, maybe I've implement it wrong :(

Comment: @AzinNilchi What about using `UserDefaults`?

Comment: @MaihanNijat I cant use a userDefault, because my data is changing dynamically and there is an array in A Controller which I get from my server! it's a little hard to explain.

Comment: @AzinNilchi Okay. And what about creating a class/ struct with having static variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do call it in viewWillDisappear of controller B:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)

    let navigationController: UINavigationController = self.navigationController!

    let controllers: [Acontroller] = navigationController.viewControllers.filter({ $0 is Acontroller }) as! [Acontroller]

    if let viewController: Acontroller = controllers.first {
        viewController.number = numberInB
        viewController.myBoolean = boolInB
    }
}
```

If the controller is in stack the values will be assigned to it.

Comment: I used your answer and it works perfectly for my work! thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please find the below steps to implement delegate.

**Step 1**:- Initialise the protocol in view controller B.

ViewcontrollerB.m

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate
{
    func didUpdateViewController(_ number: NSNumber, myBoolean: Bool);
}
```

**Step 2:-**
initalise object inside viewcontrollerB

```
var delegate:ViewControllerDelegate?
```

**Step 3:-**
Now call this delegate from back function.Here I am considering back is the function to pop viewcontroller.

```
func Back()
{
    delegate?.didUpdateViewController(numberInB!, myBoolean: boolInB!)
}
```

**Step 4:-** 
Inherit the protocol in viewcontrollerA.

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController,ViewControllerDelegate
```

**Step 5:-** 
Now Set the delegate in viewcontrollerA.

ViewcontrollerA.m

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let obj = ViewControllerB()//Initialize it as per your code
    obj.delegate = self;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

**Final Step:-**
override the delegate method.

```
   func didUpdateViewController(_ number: NSNumber, myBoolean: Bool) {
        print(number,myBoolean)
    }
```

Let me know if it worked

Answer (score 1):

If it is a small data then use `UserDefaults`:

**This is how you store data:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "Key")
```

**And this is how you get it back:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "Key")
```

Or you can use a struct with a static variable:

```
struct ShareValue {
    static var UserNum: Int = 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a delegate which other view controllers can implement and call the delegate method in `viewWillDisappear` when `isMovingFromParentViewController` is `true`

```
public protocol YourViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func didGoBack(viewController: YourViewController)
}

public class YourViewController: UIViewController {
    public weak var delegate: YourViewControllerDelegate?

    public override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if isMovingFromParentViewController {
            delegate?.didGoBack(viewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```

In your other view controller:

```
extension YourOtherViewController: YourViewControllerDelegate {
    public func didGoBack(viewController: YourViewController) {
        // Do something e.g. set your variables
    }
}
```